# dynamically update page with a users selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My question is what language is required if I had a sign up form in a dialog box, and depending on my users input, have the page update with the selection? For instance, a user would sign up and a pop up box asks to upload picture and select a few inputs and the background is dynamically updated with the user's selection. I know jquery and ajax of course has to be involved but is there any others? I have tried to google this but i have no luck.

example: https://twitter.com/signup

As you are signing up they give you a selection and if you choose one it dynamically updates the background. Forgive me if my question is vage.

Answer (score 0):

in adidtion to jQuery you will likely want to use a plugin for a rich lightbox. I recommend the [jQuery colorbox plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Here are [some other options](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/lightbox/)